# How to break a 24 hour day into 4 hour time buckets (Chron())

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, analytics, chron

Using `library(chron)`
Here is the

```
structure(c(0.876736111111111, 0.876666666666667, 0.876435185185185, 
0.876354166666667, 0.876319444444444, 0.876284722222222, 0.876134259259259, 
0.876122685185185, 0.876006944444444, 0.87587962962963, 0.875717592592593, 
0.875694444444444, 0.875613425925926, 0.875578703703704, 0.875543981481481
), format = "h:m:s", class = "times")
```

I am trying to separate these Chron() times into buckets and cannot get the ifelse statements to work
Sorry for the simple question, I am very new at R and trying to learn!

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
within(Checklist1, Checklist1$GroupTime <- 
         ifelse(Checklist$Time24 <= .1666666666666666666, 1, 
         ifelse(Checklist$Time24 > .1666666666666666666 && < .33333333333333333333, 2
         ifelse(Checklist$Time24 > .33333333333333333333 && < .50, 3
         ifelse(Checklist$Time24 > .50 & < .66666666666666666666666, 4
         ifelse(Checklist$Time24 >.66666666666666666666666 && < .83333333333333333333333333, 5
         ifelse(Checklist$Time24 > .83333333333333333333333333, 6,NA))) )
```

The 0.166 is because Chron uses % of the day to calculate the hours

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use `cut`/`findInterval` here instead of nested `ifelse` statements.

You can try :

```
Checklist1$GroupTime <- findInterval(Checklist$Time24, c(.1666, .3333, .5, .666,.833)) + 1
```